# Convert unavailable/unloaded project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project

I have a project in my solution that currently is unloaded. When I try to reload the project I get the error:

> The project has not been converted

and the project snaps back to: `projectName (unavailable)`

I don't know how this has happened and I can't seem to find a way to open the project and convert it. Is there some simple way that I am missing?

Also, the options given when right clicking the project name are: reload/edit/cut/remove.

Edit:

Turns out that sp1 had some kind of bug in it so after repairing it everything is fine now. Strange.

Comment: what is the version of VS of the project you are trying to open?

Comment: Remove it and add it back.

Comment: source project is also VS 2010? Why conversion happened if your installed VS is the same version of the project you are trying to open? Take note that the conversion of project solutions is happening only if you are trying to open a solution project which has been created using different version of what is installed in your machine

Comment: Well that's why I don't know why this has occurred and am so confused. It shouldn't need to be converted but it states that it needs to be.

Comment: @HansPassant That didn't work, same issue. :/

Comment: what's the template you are trying to open? MVC, Silverlight, or what?

Comment: Try download and install http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981